# AVPlayer is Not Playing From NSCachesDirectory?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer

Hi I am Trying to Play Video Files From NSCachesDirectory. The Player is not loading the Files from NSCachesDirectory in videoView layer.

Is it Possible to play Video from cacheDirectory Memory?
Please suggest me...

I have tried this..

```
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *cachesDir    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];   
NSString *songPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [cachesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Song.%@", downloadURL]]];

NSURL *pathurl = [[NSURL  alloc] initFileURLWithPath:songPath];
NSLog(@"--pathurl---%@",pathurl);
avPlayer =[AVPlayer playerWithURL:pathurl];
self.avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];

if ( !([avPlayer status] == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)   &&  (dataReceivedSoFar.length >10000))
    {

        avPlayerLayer.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 450);

        [[self.videoView layer] addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

        [avPlayer play];

         NSLog(@"Video IS Playing");

        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that [avPlayer status] == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay returns YES in this case. It takes some time for AVPlayer to load the item. You should can play immediately even if it's better way to track AVPlayer.status using KVO.

Lukas

EDIT: Try it this way (quick win):

```
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *cachesDir    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];   
NSString *songPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [cachesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Song.%@", downloadURL]]];

NSURL *pathurl = [[NSURL  alloc] initFileURLWithPath:songPath];
NSLog(@"--pathurl---%@",pathurl);
avPlayer =[AVPlayer playerWithURL:pathurl];

self.avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
avPlayerLayer.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 450);

[[self.videoView layer] addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

[avPlayer play];
```

Comment: After you create your AVPlayerItem, add the observer for status value like this:

Comment: I think that quick win is to remove the condition `if ( !([avPlayer status] == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)   &&  (dataReceivedSoFar.length >10000))` Just try to attach the AVPlayerLayer and call [avPlayer play] after you created AVPlayerLayer in your code.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what dataReceivedSoFar means, but I believe AVPlayer can not play partially downloaded files.

Answer (score 0):

KVO approach.
Add observer:

```
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&PlayerStatusContext];
```

Observing value

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (context == &PlayerStatusContext) {
        AVPlayer *thePlayer = (AVPlayer *)object;
        if ([thePlayer status] == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSError *error = [self.player error];
            // Respond to error: for example, display an alert sheet.
            return;
        }
        // Deal with other status change if appropriate.
        if ([thePlayer status] == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            [self play];
        }
    }
    // Deal with other change notifications if appropriate.
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
           change:change context:context];
    return;
}
```

Playing:

```
- (IBAction)play:sender {
    [self.player play];
}
```

EDITING:
As awolCZ said AVPlayer can not play partially downloaded files. But you could use something like `http://test.com/test.mp3` for URL.

Comment: but i want to play from partial download... i m able to play after download....i want to play while data is loading in cache memory..r u getting

Comment: maybe better to init AVPlayer with such url

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/test.mp3"];`

instead of downloading.

Comment: thanks for ur valuable support..but dude my download url is coming from Google Drive..and i m not able to play google drive file directly, because it asks for authentication...i m not able to get an authorized google drive file. so i plan to play from NSdata from cache memory....i am able to play audio from NSdata...but video files are not loading at all.... i hope u will be able to understand my prob..

Comment: ...hello sir any idea

Comment: I tried to play the trimmed video and found that 10,000 bytes is not enough to start play. Of course, it all depends on the quality of the video. In my case, 100000 bytes were enough for about 1 second. The video file size was 5510872 bytes. So, try to increase the criterion.

Comment: k i increased the bytes size too than also no response